# In hook_form_alter(), how can I access the entity that is being flagged?

Tags: 8, forms, flags

In `hook_form_alter()`, I want to load the entity being flagged so that I can do some processing based on the field values of that entity.

However, I can't find an entity object using `kint($form)`.  I know it must be there somewhere because the flag is correctly attached to the entity.

```
function MYMODULE_form_flagging_MYFLAG_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  kint($form);
  kint($form_state);
  // Where is the flagged entity object id?
}
```

On the flagging object, after the flagged has been saved, the entity id can be accessed like this:

```
    $flagged_entity_id = $flagging->get('entity_id')->value;
```

However, in `hook_form_alter()`, when the flag has not yet been saved for the first time, I can't find the `entity_id` in `$form`.

I thought it might be in `$form_state`, but I got a NULL result for `$form_state->get('entity_id')`.

Comment: Don't you have the flag in `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()` and from there can get the flagged entity? Idea taken from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297990/15055

Comment: Also taken from his other question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297681/27710) @leymannx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to leymannx and No Sssweat, I think I finally understand how to get the entity from a form.

To get the entity being flagged inside a flag, this is what I had to do:

```
function MYMODULE_form_flagging_MYFLAG_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      $flagging_entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
      $flagged_entity_id = $flagging_entity->get('entity_id')->value;
}
```